# Which verb's object is this phrase?

Tags: objects

> The place was called Enchanted Hunters. Query:
>   **What Indian dyes**, Diana, did thy dell
>  endorse to make of Picture Lake a very
>  blood bath of trees before the blue
>   hotel?
>  (Lolita, Vladimir Nabokov)

Which is the verb that takes the highlighted part as its object: endorse or make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's *endorse*.

Assuming *dell* means a small wooded area, they are asking Diana, what dye pigments she thought was required to capture the colors of the leaves of the trees in the dell in her painting because the speaker believes they are much too red.

[Thanks to everyone who pointed out the real meaning here]